# 2 carousel sliders on same page

Tags: jquery, carousel

Trying to add 2 carousel sliders on the same page...
however, when I copy the code below and edit with the other slider name, just the last one works properly!
JS is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //rotation speed and timer
    var speed = 5000;
    var run = setInterval('rotate()', speed);

    //grab the width and calculate left value
    var item_width = $('#slides li', '#slides_2 li').outerWidth();
    var left_value = item_width * (-1);

    //move the last item before first item, just in case user click prev button
    $('#slides li:first', '#slides_2 li:first').before($('#slides li:last', '#slides_2 li:last'));

    //set the default item to the correct position 
    $('#slides ul', '#slides_2 ul').css({
        'left': left_value
    });

    //if user clicked on prev button
    $('#prev', '#prev_2').click(function() {

        //get the right position            
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul', '#slides_2 ul').css('left')) + item_width;

        //slide the item            
        $('#slides ul', '#slides_2 ul').animate({
            'left': left_indent
        }, 200, function() {

            //move the last item and put it as first item               
            $('#slides li:first', '#slides_2 li:first').before($('#slides li:last', '#slides_2 li:last'));

            //set the default item to correct position
            $('#slides ul', '#slides_2 ul').css({
                'left': left_value
            });

        });

        //cancel the link behavior            
        return false;
    });

    //if user clicked on next button
    $('#next', '#next_2').click(function() {

        //get the right position
        var left_indent = parseInt($('#slides ul', '#slides_2 ul').css('left')) - item_width;

        //slide the item
        $('#slides ul', '#slides_2 ul').animate({
            'left': left_indent
        }, 200, function() {

            //move the first item and put it as last item
            $('#slides li:last', '#slides_2 li:last').after($('#slides li:first', '#slides_2 li:first'));

            //set the default item to correct position
            $('#slides ul', '#slides_2 ul').css({
                'left': left_value
            });

        });

        //cancel the link behavior
        return false;
    });

    //if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it
    $('#slides', '#slides_2').hover(

        function() {
            clearInterval(run);
        },
        function() {
            run = setInterval('rotate()', speed);
        }
    );
});

//a simple function to click next link
//a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin :)  
function rotate() {
    $('#next', '#next_2').click();
}
```

I got this code from this website:
http://www.queness.com/post/923/create-a-simple-infinite-carousel-with-jquery
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper jQuery syntax for multiple selectors is:

```
$('#slides li, #slides_2 li')...
```

That said, there are a zillion free carousels out there that are properly abstracted, which avoids this whole mess altogether.

http://bxslider.com

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel